# Broken for loop returning 4 results instead of 2

Tags: java, xml, for-loop, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML document. I get all of the results returned correctly, but when I parse them in my embedded for loop, things don't work out quite right.

What I want:

```
Var #1 
Var #2
```

What I get:

```
Var #1
Var #2
Var #1
Var #2
```

I have an initial for loop to go through the main document and get all of the variables the first time, and then I have a second for loop which goes through the child elements of the document. As above, the for loop inside the for loop returns all the correct results, but prints them twice.

```
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("update");

        for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = nodes.item(i); 

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
            {

                if (update_type.equals("JGRP"))
                { 
                    String user = getValue("first-name", element) + " " + getValue("last-name", element);                                               
                    NodeList cNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("member-group");

                    for (int z=0; z < cNodes.getLength(); z++)
                    { 
                        Node cNode = cNodes.item(z);

                        if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                        {   
                            Element cElement = (Element)cNode; 
                            String group_name = getValue("name",cElement);
                            g_name = group_name; 

                            System.out.println(g_name);
                        }
                    }                           
                }
            }
        }
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your first loop isn't adding them twice? Have you tried debugging and confirming that your list of nodes is indeed length 2?

Comment: @dckuehn Yes, my list of nodes is length 2. How would my first loop be adding them twice?

Comment: I don't know.  You didn't include the first loop.  But you did say it goes through the list twice, once for parents and then for children.  I just thought it might be a possibility.

Comment: What is the size of cNodes?

Comment: @dckuehn the length of cNodes is 2. i did getLength

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally get it.

```
    // This loop runs twice total
    for (int i=0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        ...

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
        {
            ...
            if (update_type.equals("JGRP"))
            { 
                ...
                // This loop runs twice total
                for (int z=0; z < cNodes.getLength(); z++)
                { 
                    ...

                    if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {   
                        ...

                        System.out.println(g_name);
                    }
                }                           
            }
        }
    }
```

If your outer loop runs twice, that's 4 total times your inner loop runs.  So it prints 4 total elements, each twice.